# Is this code threadsafe? Static method modifying http servlet request

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety

I've a class with a `static` method which takes two parameters- `HttpServletRequest request` and `HttpServletResponse response` :

```
public class RequestProcessor {
    public static processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //read request and write data to response
    }
}
```

Several threads can be calling RequestProcessor.processRequest method at same time.

After doing some research, my understanding is that since stacks are local to threads so it shouldn't be a problem but I am not sure if this code is still thread safe because HttpServletRequest request and HttpServletResponse response are not immutable

Comment: So long as `processRequest` isn't modifying any static class variables, should you even be worried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that should be absolutely fine, so long as the method isn't using/modifying any shared mutable state, and you only call it within normal servlet processing - so each thread that calls it will be passing in the request/response that it's currently handling.

(If multiple threads start modifying the same request/response, that would certainly cause problems.)

Answer (score 5):

You should understand how `Servlet` containers work. The container holds a thread pool. When it receives a request, it will pick an available thread. In that thread (YMMV), it creates  `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects. It then gets a reference to the `Servlet` that is meant to handle the request. Finally, still in the thread, it will call `Servlet#service(..)` passing in the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects it previously created.

The fact that a method is `static` makes no difference. You need to know if the object references you have in the current scope may be accessed from another `Thread`.

If we assume, in your example, that the `HttpServletRequest` parameter is not shared with any other `Thread`, then, in the scope of your `processRequest` method, it will be thread-safe as no other thread can come access it and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling this method with the same objects from different threads (and modifying them), then no, it isn't thread safe.

If you *are* modifying them across threads, you would need to add locks around those objects so you don't get any unexpected and strange behavior.

Comment: Most objects *won't* throw ConcurrentModificationException - they'll just behave oddly, or not see all updates from all threads etc. I can't remember seeing CME other than from collections.